# Can this sum be written as a matrix product?

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

Given matrices $D,C$ and vector $\vec{\lambda}$, I am wondering if the sum  $\sum_kc_{jk}\lambda_kd_{kl}$ can be written as some sort of matrix product. The context comes from the following scenario:

Say we have some operator $A$ and want to act it on an expansion over some basis $\{\phi_j\}$, ie, we want to calculate $A\sum\alpha_j\phi_j$. We can do this by expanding each $\phi_j=\sum_kc_{jk}\chi_k$ where the $\chi_k$ are the eigenvectors of $A$ with corresponding eigenvalues $\lambda_k$. The calculation now becomes

$$
A\sum_j\alpha_j\sum_kc_{jk}\chi_k=\sum_{j,k}\alpha_jc_{jk}\lambda_k\chi_k
$$

Now given the previously mentioned change of basis matrix $C=(c_{jk})$, we can use its inverse $C^{-1}=D=(d_{kj})$ to expand the eigenbasis for $A$ back into our basis $\{\phi_j\}$: $\chi_k=\sum d_{kj}\phi_j$ and we can expand our result from earlier:

$$
\sum_{j,k}\alpha_jc_{jk}\lambda_k\chi_k=\sum_{j,k,l}\alpha_jc_{jk}\lambda_kd_{kl}\phi_l
$$

the sum of interest from earlier is seen here as $e_{jl}=\sum_kc_{jk}\lambda_kd_{kl}$. If I consider the matrix $E=(e_{jl})$, can $E$ be written in simple terms with respect to $C,D$ and $\vec{\lambda}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can think of is if we let
$$\Lambda = \text{diag}( \lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n ),$$that is, if it has matrix elements $$\Lambda_{kl} = \delta_{k,l} \lambda_k,$$ then using your notation we would have
$$ E = C \Lambda D.$$